# Incomplete type when compiling recursive template to call static member function

Tags: c++, templates, cygwin

I am compiling this code with g++ version 3.4.4 on windows:-

```
#include <iostream>

template< int i >
class LOOP{
 public:
    static inline void EXEC(int* count){
        (*count)++;
            LOOP< i-1 >::EXEC(count);
   }
};

template<> class LOOP< 0 >{
  public:
    static inline void EXEC(int* count){
   (*count)++;
   }
};

 int main(int i){

int barely = 0;
LOOP< 1000 >::EXEC(&barely);
 }
```

It complains, incomplete type LOOP<500> used in nested name specifier and has a list of the previous instantiations before it, "instantiated from static void LOOP::EXEC(int *) with i - 1000" and so on.

When I change it to LOOP<100> it compiles fine though.

*EDIT* I am running this on cygwin if that affects the implementation limits.

Comment: Perhaps you are facing an implementation limit?

Comment: Ouch. That shot on the foot must hurt

Comment: Is this something probably better asked directly to the lists for gnu g++?  I want to make sure I'm not making a language error.

Comment: Try `LOOP<255>` and `LOOP<256>`. Just a hunch.

Comment: 255, 256 and 257 compile fine.

Comment: I would wager you're hitting some limitation of the compiler when it tries to generate the various LOOP variants... i.e LOOP<1000>, LOOP<999>, LOOP<998>, etc...

Try a newer version of g++ maybe?

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-ftemplate-depth=1005`?

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient compiler? (And why are you using ALL_CAPS for your identifiers? Idiomatic style reserves ALL_CAPS for macros.)

Comment: @Fanael, that command line, in -ftemplate-depth-1005 (not equals) fixes it.  I can't accept your answer though because it's a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit the implementation's template depth limit. You can increase the limit by compiling with `-ftemplate-depth=1005` (modern GCC) or `-ftemplate-depth-1005` (older GCC).